# Not able to set date

Tags: html, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I am getting a date value in Jquery from a form on update click. But I am unable to set it in date input type in the modal.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.editbtn').on('click', function () {

                    $('#editmodal').modal('show');
                    $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var data = $tr.children("td").map(function () {
                        return $(this).text();
                    }).get();

                    console.log(data[0]); // format of date: "12-08-2021" on console
                   $('#Bdate').val(data[0]);
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row g-5 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-auto">
        <label for="size" class="col-form-label">Date Added</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto ms-1">
        <input type="date" name="date_added" id="Bdate" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is to set the default date from Jquery which I am receiving.

Comment: am i dumb or is there no editbtn classed element. Therefore there cant be a click on it and the function never calls?

Comment: To reliably set the value of a date input you need to use ISO formatted dates, eg `2021-08-12` or `2021-12-08`, depending on whether your original date was DMY or MDY